# NVMe SSD not visible in disk utilities when install Ubuntu 18.10 on macbook 2018

Tags: partitioning, ssd, macbook, macbook-pro, nvme

As the title says I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a MacBook 2018.

I installed reFind. Ubuntu boots properly when I set `nomodeset` in the kernel options.

Once the desktop loaded I do `lspci -k` but no driver loaded for `Mass Storage controller: Apple Inc. ANS2 NVME Controller (rev01)`.

I run the following commands:

```
modprobe nvme
echo 106b 2005 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/new_id
```

Run `lspci -k` again and I can see `Kernel in use: nvme`

Check my devices and I can find `/dev/nvme0`

From there I would like to prepare my partitions but neither `parted`, `gparted` or `fdisk` is detecting the device.

Encryption (Vault) is disabled.

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple uses a proprietary SSD controller that Linux drivers do not exist for yet. Until drivers are made, you will need to install to an external device to install ubuntu.

https://forum.level1techs.com/t/linux-doesnt-support-t2-as-a-ssd-controller-apples-t2-secure-boot-chip-is-blocking-usage-of-linux-in-t2-chip-macs/134832

Drivers appear to require a signature from Microsoft or Apple so they are most likely long ways out. Multiple other devices have been "impossible" to install Linux onto before, but it will probably be faster to break the T2 and SSD controller than to wait for official support.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208330

TL;DR Secure boot disables allows you to boot off of an external device but won't let you install to your hard disk.